# Solidworks on windows 7 UAC request at every login

Tags: uac, prompt, solidworks

Is there a way to stop solidworks from requiring a UAC permission prompt every time the system is booted up? It is apparently trying to activate a server at startup. Is this an authentication service, and if so why does it need to be admin?

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to disable UAC for one application, detailed in the article:
[Disable User Account Control (UAC) for certain Windows Vista applications](http://www.vista4beginners.com/Disable-UAC-for-certain-applications)

However, given the complexity of this solution, the cure is worse than the disease.
Disabling UAC is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Change User Account Control Settings

Move the slider to the very bottom. 
No more UAC.

In my opinion, if you're intelligent enough to find and join this site, then you're intelligent enough to not need UAC.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could [disable UAC](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/12/30/how-to-disable-and-turn-off-uac-in-windows-7/). If you are worried that this would make you significantly more vulnerable to viruses and such, [don't be](http://www.sophos.com/blogs/chetw/g/2009/11/03/windows-7-vulnerable).